# A variation of Viète's formula -- an infinite product of nested radicals

Tags: calculus, pi, infinite-product, nested-radicals, golden-ratio

[Viète's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula) expresses an infinite product of nested radicals in terms of $\pi$.

Let
$$a_1=\sqrt2,\quad a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}.$$
Note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=2.$ Then
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}2=\frac{\sqrt2}2\times\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}2\times\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}}2\times\dots=\frac2\pi.$$
Let's consider a variation of this problem. Let
$$b_1=\sqrt1=1,\quad b_n=\sqrt{1+b_{n-1}}.$$
It's easy to see that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=\phi,$ where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ is the golden ratio.

Is it possible to find a closed form for this infinite product?
$$\begin{align}
P&=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b_n}\phi=\frac{\sqrt1}\phi\times\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt1}}\phi\times\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt1}}}\phi\times\dots\\
&\approx0.5094909728475357551307361756807565841868\dots
\end{align}$$
Or, at least, to find alternative representations and establish some of its properties: is it irrational? is it transcendental?

Comment: It might be related to the [Paris constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParisConstant.html).